# Validating user input in JTextFields (Java)

Tags: java, swing, validation, jtextfield

I am trying to validate user input into text boxes. I am checking whether the text box is populated or not and if it's not I need to alert the user to which text box isn't populated. My problem is that I need a way of returning which text box / variable is empty. I am aware I will need to pass 2 values in, one being the content of the text box and the other, an identifier of the text box.

Currently I have this (found on StackOverflow) which checks if each variable in the array is populated.

```
public boolean areAllNotEmpty(String... text){

    for(String s : text) {
        if(s == null || "".equals(s)) {

            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

I would like it to also return something like this (commented):

```
public boolean areAllNotEmpty(String... text){

    for(String s : text) {
        if(s == null || "".equals(s)) {
           // return textbox name / value OR show alert box with "Forename missing" etc  
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

I implemented this method before on a C# project but it requires passing in one text box at a time with multiple method calls which I'm guessing isn't great.

```
public static bool IsFieldNull(TextBox currentText, string type)
    {
        bool allOk = false;

        if (currentText.Text == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error - '" + type + "' field cannot be left blank, please enter some data in this field");
            currentText.Focus();
            return allOk;
        }

        else
        {
            allOk = true;
            return allOk;
        }
```

This is how it is called in C#.

```
Validation.IsFieldNull(txtBoxFixtureDate, "Fixture Date") && Validation.IsFieldNull(txtBoxTime, "Time")
```

If any of that doesn't make sense, let me know.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What kind of text boxes? Like a `JTextField`? If not, please show us your TextBox class so we know what we're working with

Comment: yes, JTextFields. Sorry, will amend question.

Answer (score 1):

You could pass the components to the method and return ones that are empty like this:

```
public List<JTextField> getEmptyFields(JTextField... textFields) {
    List<JTextField> emptyFields = new ArrayList<JTextField>();
    for (JTextField field : textFields) {
        if (field.getText().isEmpty()) {
            emptyFields.add(field);
        }
    }

    return emptyFields;
}
```

Then you can just check the `size()` of the returned list to determine if there was an empty field and deal with them accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

It's not pretty useful to validate when a submit button is pressed, it's better to validate when the error is happening. You may consider using [InputVerifier](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/InputVerifier.html) . Then you know when it's in valid state or not. Apart from that if you are using java7 or above you could take a look to `JLayer` to decorate components which are not in valid state. See here for more examples [Decorate components with JLayer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/jlayer.html#validation).